# Rotation a model in all axes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to rotate my gameObject in all axes (x,y,z) with mouse drag function. The gameObject should be rotated smoothly on release. With some adjustments I have achieved to rotate it in y-direction when mouse drags Left-Right. However I am finding it really complicated to rotate in the other 2 axes. Can someone explain how do I achieve this?

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Collections;
 using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class RotateModel : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler {
     public float rotationSpeed;
     public float rotationDamping;

     private float _rotationVelocity;
     private float _preRotationVelocity;
     private float _preRotationVelocityY;
     private float _rotationVelocityY;
     private bool _dragged;

     public void OnBeginDrag (PointerEventData eventData) {
         _dragged = true;
     }

     public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData) {
         _preRotationVelocity = eventData.delta.x * rotationSpeed;
         _rotationVelocity = Mathf.Clamp (_preRotationVelocity, -8f, 8f);
         this.transform.Rotate (Vector3.up, -_rotationVelocity, Space.World);
     }

     public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData eventData) {
         _dragged = false;
     }

     private void Update () {
         if (!_dragged && !Mathf.Approximately (_rotationVelocity, 0)) {
             float deltaVelocity = Mathf.Min (
                 Mathf.Sign (_rotationVelocity) * Time.deltaTime * rotationDamping,
                 Mathf.Sign (_rotationVelocity) * _rotationVelocity
             );
             _rotationVelocity -= deltaVelocity;
             this.transform.Rotate (Vector3.up, -_rotationVelocity, Space.World);
         }
      
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to rotate objects in 3D. So the first step should be to determine what model you want to use. Also consider if you need to allow rotation around all three axes, and if you can provide tools to align rotation to other objects. Another point is if you want to rotate around the objects local axes, or the world axes, or allow switching between the two. Some examples of rotation models:

**Separate axes**

Use a key or button to determine what axis you should rotate around. This is probably the easiest alternative to implement, just switch `Vector3.up` for other vectors depending on the pressed key or button.

**Rotation widgets**

Render 3D circles around your object for each axis you want to rotate around. When the user clicks on the circle you would rotate around that axis. I personally prefer this model, but it might be the most difficult to implement. This [blender example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58882/display-rotate-manipulator-controls) shows this style.

[image: rotation widgets]

**Virtual trackball**

As the name suggest this essentially simulates a virtual trackball, and allow for rotation in all three dimensions at the same time. [This article about 3d rotation](https://www.mattkeeter.com/projects/rotation/) explains the functioning, and links to a paper with more details. I personally find that this can be complicated to use, since all axes are affected and you cannot rotate around each axis in turn.